# Cron Job 404 Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am trying to run a cron job in our PHP Codeigniter web app.  I am running it with the below command through our hosting provider's site (Pagoda Box).

```
php index.php cron _product_exp_id_auto
```

I am able to receive an email showing the result, which says **404 Page Not Found**.

We have other cron jobs running in the same cron.php file, and they work fine using the same format cron job command.  This is the function:

```
function _product_exp_id_auto() {
    $query = 'SET @_temp_id := 0;
        UPDATE products SET _product_exp_id = (@_temp_id := @_temp_id+4) WHERE products.active=1;
        UPDATE products set _product_exp_id = NULL where products.active=0;';

        $this->db->query($query);
}
```

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: The underscore at the start of the function name makes the function inaccessible via url. So it probably does the same for the command line.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try removing it and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Samutz noted in the comment, the _ in the function name was causing the problem.

```
function product_exp_id_auto() {
```

Works!